# Finding the VPC that my project associated with in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

Just a naïve question.. I am not able to locate the answer.

In Google Cloud (GCP), how can we locate the VPC that a project is associated with.

I am aware that every project when created, is by default associated with a VPC. But I am unable to locate the VPC after I create my free GCP account. There is a project created by default. When I go VPC Network section, it says no resources to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps

1.login to your [console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

2.then from the top select the project for which you want to find the VPC.

3.after you selected the project then in the top-left corner of the console click on the icon with three horizontal lines.

4.here in the left sidebar scroll down there you will see 'NETWORKING' under that click on "VPC Network".

Comment: Actually I tried the same way where I was getting resources not available message. After the enablement of Compute Engine API, I am able to see the VPC. Thanks your time looking into my question and respond.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud (GCP), to locate the VPC that a project is associated with a project , you can follow below steps:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select the project you want to view the VPC for.
3. In the Console, navigate to the Navigation menu > VPC network > VPC networks .

Google Cloud creates a default VPC. The instance that you will create will be  located in that VPC. You can create a new VPC but you cannot move that instance to the new VPC. You would need to create an image of the instance and then launch a new instance in the new VPC.

Also mentioned in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#:%7E:text=Unless%20you%20choose%20to%20disable,pre%2Dpopulated%20IPv6%20firewall%20rules.) on VPC networks:

> Projects can contain multiple VPC networks. Unless you create an organizational policy that prohibits it, new projects start with a default network (an auto mode VPC network) that has one subnetwork (subnet) in each region.

You can also refer to this [documentation](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/1229?locale=uk&parent=catalog) for more information.

Comment: Actually I tried this approach earlier where I was getting 'no resources available' message. But after I enabled the Compute Engine API, then I am able to see the default VPC. Thanks for taking your time to respond my question. I really appreciate it!